# Нужно перевести код из Pascal в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    var
      n, k: integer;

    begin
      write('n = ');
      readln(n);
      k := trunc(exp(ln(n) / 3)); //целая часть от кубического корня
      if k * (k + 1) + (k + 2) = n then write('Можно: ', n, ' = ', k, ' * ', k + 1, ' * ', k + 2)
      else write('Нельзя');
      readln
    end.
```

Comment: где именно у вас проблемы?

Comment: Раз нужно, то переводите, конечно. Мы не против.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь принято писать с чем именно возникли трудности и по возможности предоставлять код, как результат ваших попыток решить проблему :)

**Ваш код на Python 3:**

```
from math import trunc, exp, log1p

n = int(input('n = '))
k =  trunc(exp(log1p(n) / 3))
if k * (k + 1) + (k + 2) == n:
    print(f'Можно: {n} = {k} * {k+1} * {k+2}')
else:
    print('Нельзя')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, исправлю при следующих запросах!